# Doubletap listener in background

Tags: java, android

I would create an app for get the double tap also if the app is in background.
I create this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener
{

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
    private int counter = 0;

    // Called when the activity is first created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event)
    {
        counter++;
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, String.valueOf(counter));
        return true;
    }
 //..........................
}
```

if the app is open in the log i see the number of count of double tap increase, if the app work in background the number is blocked.
There is a way for fix it? or i have to create a services? i need a grafic app and service, there is a way for create just one with both things?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy answer to this. Normally it is NOT possibile because an App cannot interact with other pieces of Android interface that is OUTSIDE the App itselfs. But if the device has Root Permissions it's possibile to directly read the Touchscreen and intercept all touch events.

An alternative method that not requires Root exists but I discurage to use it: place a fullscreen View that acts as a transparent layer and that intercepts all the events. However this method has few disadvantages: slows down graphic performance of WHOLE device (expecially while running games), could interfere with user experience while touching interactive areas (buttons, checkboxes, etc...) and however could not work well by loosing some touching events.

Comment: I would like to be able to take this event even on the screen off, if I take the accelerometer data according to you is a good idea?
I am afraid that the battery consumption will be high, is there a better solution?

Comment: When the display is turned off even the "sensitive touching part" of it is turned off. It depends of the Kernel in use, but 99% of them do that. Only few devices (and their relative Kernels) leaves active the "sensitive touchscreen part" when they just turn off the display part. Using the accellerometer I THINK it's not possibile because small vibrations could generate false positive most of the times.